# I can’t hear others on FaceTime calls when I’m talking on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, audio, facetime

I've ran into this strange issue a while back and I cannot recall which iOS update it has been along since. Bascially whenever I'm using FaceTime, regardless of device, iPhone and MacBook Pro, the other person I am talking to gets muted when I say something. It is really hard to maintain a good conversation as one often speaks at the same time as the other by nature. I was using AirPods Gen 2 earlier but switched to AirPods Pro recently and the issue persisted.

I thought FaceTime supported duplex conversations.

Is there an audio setting where my speaking cuts off my hearing of others, or is it a bug that I can solve in some way?

Comment: Have you tried using the speakers on the laptop? As I have never seen that behavior.

Comment: I will update you once I've had a facetime call so I can test it with built in speakers and microphone.

Comment: When you say muted - in a three way conversation can no one hear them or is it just you that can’t hear them? Speaker phones almost always mute the speakers when they detect your mic engaging to prevent feedback.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's on my end and what you said about preventing feedback seems reasonable. I've never been in a three way call, so I can't answer that for you. Anyway is there a possibility to disable this behavior? As I mentioned in my post it has been introduced recently and it's starting to annoy me quite a lot.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning is that other people I know who also use AirPods together with an iPhone are not isolated when speaking and can hear me simultaneously.

Comment: I often experience the same, especially if it’s loud on both ends and when I use airpods, then even if I’m not talking, the other person gets muted. A partial workaround for the latter is to mute my mic, then I can fully hear the other person. ‍♂️